# Integrate $\int \frac{1}{(1-x)(1+x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Integrate $$\int \frac{1}{(1-x)(1+x)}dx$$

$$\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}dx$$

$$=\tanh^{-1}(x)+C$$

When I look on Desmos though, this is only **part** of the answer?

[image]

The **blue** is the function that it is supposed to be, and the **red** is the derivative of the answer I got. As you can see it's right, but only the **red** is shaded, the other two blue regions are not. Why is this? How can I fix this? My answer is correct, right?

Comment: You can integrate this simply by doing a partial fraction decomposition on $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1+x)}$. Also, your integral is missing a $dx$!

Comment: I know I can, but why is this wrong

Comment: As a general advice: dont trust too much on desmos on any other graphical or CAS software. Desmos fail sometimes representing functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x=\pm 1$ are simple poles for the integrand function, in particular non-integrable singularities. That implies $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{1-x^2}$ has no meaning if $1$ or $-1$ belong to $[a,b]$. On the other hand,
$$ \frac{1}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{1+x}\right)$$
clearly holds for any $x\neq \pm 1$, hence if $1$ and $-1$ **do not** belong to $[a,b]$ we have
$$ \int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\log|x+1|-\log|x-1|\right).$$
That explains why the depicted primitive only exists in $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're integrating your function $1/(1-x^2)$ on $[1,2]$. Yet, it's singular at $1$, so any definite integral that goes over $\pm 1$ will not be correct.